# sublime text 2 concurrent access on files

Tags: sftp, sublimetext2, swapfile

Im using Sublime text 2 with plugin SFTP to edit files on server.

It there an option to raise some kinda flag when a file Im trying to edit is already open by somone else ? (using swape file or something )

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure but I'd guess you'd have to ask the developer of the SFTP plugin.  Their support is here: http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp